# How to copy one custom list to another custom list (approximately 600 items)

Tags: development, web-part, sandbox-solution

I have one master list from which I wish to query and create a subset of this in a new custom list. The code I have so far works, but it is extremely slow and occasionally hits the hard limit of the 30 second request time of a sandboxed solution.

The master list contains about 700 items and I will need to copy up to 500 to the subset list.

Is there a more efficient way of running this query? What is the best practice for this sort of task?

```
                string filterQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='milestone' /><Value Type='Text'>4</Value></Eq></Where>";

                SPQuery query = new Query(); 
                query.Query = filterQuery;
                SPList list = web.Lists["Projects"];
                SPListItemCollection collListItemSrc = list.GetItems(query);
                SPListItemCollection collListItemDest = web.Lists[documentTitle].Items;

                string projectId = "Project name";

                foreach (SPListItem oListItemSrc in collListItemSrc)
                {

                    SPListItem oListItemDest = collListItemDest.Add();


                    oListItemDest["ProjectID"] = projectId;
                    oListItemDest["ProjectName"] = oListItemSrc["ProjectName"];
                    oListItemDest["Owner"] = oListItemSrc["Owner"];
                    oListItemDest["Manager"] = oListItemSrc["Manager"];
                    oListItemDest["Objective"] = oListItemSrc["Objective"];
                    oListItemDest["Duration"] = oListItemSrc["Duration"];
                    oListItemDest["Milestone"] = oListItemSrc["Milestone"];
                    oListItemDest.Update(); 
                 }
```

Comment: Is it one time operation, or you will use it again?

Comment: What do you do in GetProjectName()? and btw query.ViewFields and query.ViewFieldsOnly could help on your performance too.

Comment: It will be used many times programmatically based on any search criteria specified by the end user.

Answer (score 2):

**If it is one time operation i.e. Static, you can:**

1- Make a list view of the source list with your filters
2- Export the view to Excel
3- Make a datasheet view of the destination List with matching columns to Excel Spreadsheet
4- Copy data from Excel sheet to Datasheet view of List!

OR

Use [Excel Add-in](http://rstagg.com/2010/04/13/how-to-bulk-upload-and-synchronize-data-into-sharepoint-using-the-excel-add-in-and-sharepoint-designer-workflows/) to synchronize data from Source Excel to destination List!

**If it is more than one time operation i.e. Dynamic:**

Have a look at [List Item Performance - Updating Large Lists](http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/list-item-performance-updating-large.html) and [SharePoint: Using Batch-Updates to speed up performance?](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/01/20/sharepoint-using-batch-updates-to-speed-up-performance/) ... I don't really know if RPC calls/Batch Adding items work in Sandbox environment or not, but you can give it a try!

Have a look at [How to: Update List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx), they say update but of course can be used for Adding items!

**EVEN THAT DOESN'T SOLVES THE PROBLEM**

You can then schedule this task for Timer Job, keep a list with the user specified criteria and use it as a scheduled task for Timer Job... You can also notify the user about completion of task from within the Timer Job! I usually prefer this approach if the task is time consuming, and keep user posted about this! Let me know if you want more information on this!

I hope this helps!

Comment: The batch update is a little tricky to get right but works extremely well

Comment: Great reply, thanks for the information. I shall give it a go and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

James,

What about just creating a new View for the current list, which filters to show only what you need?

Or if you don't need all the columns, perhaps creating a second list with specific Lookup columns referencing the first?